# Number of nodes = 2, RF = 2: where do the reads come from?

Tags: cassandra

How can I detect that the data is latest/synchronized between nodes in a A/A C* cluster? Also, in number of nodes = 2, RF = 2 scenario, can we say for sure that the reads (RC=1) are happening locally (or not)?

Answer (score 0):

1) To keep the data consistent on two nodes, you need to run a repair job

2) On where the reads are responding depends on how you are querying, if you are querying from cqlsh, then it comes from the node you are connected to. If you are programmatically reading using the drivers, then it depends on the load balancing policy in use.

You can get more info from the DataStax Documentation -

http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/data-consistency